# Firefox Extension automatic update not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, automatic-updates

I followed instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Update_RDF_Format) and after installed I opened the console mode to debug but the log stuck there without any response:
The console just shows something like following and nothing more output:

```
*** LOG addons.updates: Requesting https://www.extension.host.com/update.rdf
```

My `install.rdf` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">

    <em:id>webmailchecker@mozilla.doslash.org</em:id>
    <em:name>WebMail Checker for Firefox</em:name>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:description>WebMail Checker</em:description>
    <em:updateURL>https://www.extension.host.com/update.rdf</em:updateURL>

    <!-- Firefox -->
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>3.6</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>23.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

And `update.rdf` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RDF:RDF xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <RDF:Description about="urn:mozilla:extension:webmailchecker@mozilla.doslash.org">
    <em:updates>
      <RDF:Seq>

        <!-- Each li is a different version of the same add-on -->
        <RDF:li>
          <RDF:Description>
            <em:version>1.0</em:version> 
            <em:targetApplication>
              <RDF:Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>23.*</em:maxVersion>
                <em:updateLink>https://www.extension.host.com/firefox.xpi</em:updateLink>

              </RDF:Description>
            </em:targetApplication>
          </RDF:Description>
        </RDF:li>

        <RDF:li>
          <RDF:Description>
            <em:version>2.0</em:version>
            <em:targetApplication>
              <RDF:Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>23.*</em:maxVersion>
                <em:updateLink>https://www.extension.host.com/firefox_2.0.xpi</em:updateLink>
              </RDF:Description>
            </em:targetApplication>
          </RDF:Description>
        </RDF:li>

      </RDF:Seq>
    </em:updates>
  </RDF:Description>
</RDF:RDF>
```

In the server side, both of the update.rdf and the xpi file are returned as `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` and I have configured the mimemapping in the `web.xml` as the following:

```xml
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xpi</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-xpinstall</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>rdf</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Anything I missed? The automatic update is just not working.

Comment: That's strange - the way I read `AddonUpdateChecker.jsm`, there is only one scenario where it would output that one log message and nothing else. It should only happen if `<em:updates>` is empty. Maybe an older version of your `update.rdf` is stuck in the cache?

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Thanks for the reply.Stuck in cache? My first version update.rdf is just as above. I have tried to clear the browser cache and history before. Is the cache you mentioned that I cleared? And I can access the update.rdf  by typing into the address bar

Comment: Wrong guess then. I'm out of ideas, your setup seems correct and there should definitely be more log messages.

Comment: thx. On the server side, when I click check for update, I can see the update url is handled but I can not see something like update entry detected from the console. I will check more

Comment: @WladimirPalant I tried to download the extension manually with the updateLink `https://localhost:8443/firefox.xpi` by typing into the address bar in firefox. But I got error like "the add-on could not be downloaded due to connection failure on localhost". Do you have any idea? But in the server side the fetch file operation was responsed.

Comment: Sorry, ignore it. It's server error. Currently it's just the update.rdf file fetched but the updateLink is not fetched after this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I look back to this issue again and finally solved this. And I update the answer in case anyone else need this. 
I looked into the source code AddonUpdateChecker.jsm which I should do this earlier.
I used javascript debugger to debug the update. Before this, I really didn't see any logs indicating that the I should have builtInCertificate.
And found that it's looking into the pref values about certificates.
Which are **extensions.install.requireBuiltInCerts** and **extensions.update.requireBuiltInCerts**.

Set these two prefs values to false and the udpate works.

Others with different ssl certificate may not meet this problem maybe.